# Unicorn Crash Loop

Tags: deployment, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-1.9.2, ubuntu-11.04, unicorn

I'm trying to setup Unicorn with Nginx on my Ubuntu 11.04 machine. I compiled Ruby from the source, (previously tried RVM but had numerous problems with that) and now after installing unicorn (as well as rails 3.1.0 RC4) it has a strange issue where it crashes and then tries to run the part that's crashing repeatedly, or at least that's what it looks like.

### Output

```
root@server-pc:/usr/local/blog# unicorn_rails
I, [2011-07-15T13:14:50.577149 #23269]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:8080 fd=3
I, [2011-07-15T13:14:50.577677 #23269]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2011-07-15T13:14:50.579412 #23269]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2011-07-15T13:14:50.581087 #23271]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=23271
I, [2011-07-15T13:14:50.581599 #23271]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup': You have already activated rack 1.3.1, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.3.0. Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:17:in `setup'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `rescue in require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from /usr/local/blog/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from /usr/local/blog/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from /usr/local/blog/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from config.ru:1:in `new'
        from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.0.1/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.0.1/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `block in builder'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.0.1/bin/unicorn_rails:139:in `call'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.0.1/bin/unicorn_rails:139:in `block in rails_builder'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:673:in `call'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:673:in `build_app!'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:549:in `init_worker_process'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:567:in `worker_loop'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:475:in `spawn_missing_workers'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:135:in `start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.0.1/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/unicorn_rails:19:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/unicorn_rails:19:in `<main>'
E, [2011-07-15T13:14:52.259536 #23269] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 23271 exit 1> worker=0
I, [2011-07-15T13:14:52.259859 #23269]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2011-07-15T13:14:52.263092 #23274]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=23274
I, [2011-07-15T13:14:52.263665 #23274]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
^C/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup': You have already activated rack 1.3.1, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.3.0. Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:17:in `setup'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `rescue in require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from /usr/local/blog/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from /usr/local/blog/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from /usr/local/blog/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from config.ru:1:in `new'
        from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.0.1/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.0.1/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `block in builder'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.0.1/bin/unicorn_rails:139:in `call'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.0.1/bin/unicorn_rails:139:in `block in rails_builder'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:673:in `call'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:673:in `build_app!'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:549:in `init_worker_process'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:567:in `worker_loop'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:475:in `spawn_missing_workers'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:486:in `maintain_worker_count'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:270:in `join'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.0.1/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/unicorn_rails:19:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/unicorn_rails:19:in `<main>'
E, [2011-07-15T13:14:53.967107 #23269] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 23274 exit 1> worker=0
I, [2011-07-15T13:14:53.967420 #23269]  INFO -- : master complete
```

This project was working just fine in Windows (minus the Unicorn gem as it's not compatible with Windows).

### Project Gems

```
 root@server-pc:/usr/local/blog# bundle list
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (3.1.0.rc4)
  * actionpack (3.1.0.rc4)
  * activemodel (3.1.0.rc4)
  * activerecord (3.1.0.rc4)
  * activeresource (3.1.0.rc4)
  * activesupport (3.1.0.rc4)
  * ansi (1.3.0)
  * arel (2.1.3)
  * bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4)
  * builder (3.0.0)
  * bundler (1.0.15)
  * capistrano (2.6.0)
  * devise (1.4.2)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * execjs (1.2.0)
  * highline (1.6.2)
  * hike (1.1.0)
  * i18n (0.6.0)
  * jquery-rails (1.0.12)
  * kgio (2.6.0)
  * libv8 (3.3.10.2)
  * mail (2.3.0)
  * mime-types (1.16)
  * multi_json (1.0.3)
  * net-scp (1.0.4)
  * net-sftp (2.0.5)
  * net-ssh (2.1.4)
  * net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
  * orm_adapter (0.0.5)
  * polyglot (0.3.1)
  * rack (1.3.0)
  * rack-cache (1.0.2)
  * rack-mount (0.8.1)
  * rack-ssl (1.3.2)
  * rack-test (0.6.0)
  * rails (3.1.0.rc4)
  * railties (3.1.0.rc4)
  * raindrops (0.7.0)
  * rake (0.9.2)
  * rdoc (3.8)
  * redcarpet (1.17.2)
  * sass (3.1.4)
  * sass-rails (3.1.0.rc.4)
  * sprockets (2.0.0.beta.10)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.3)
  * therubyracer (0.9.2)
  * thor (0.14.6)
  * tilt (1.3.2)
  * treetop (1.4.9)
  * turn (0.8.2)
  * tzinfo (0.3.29)
  * uglifier (1.0.0)
  * unicorn (4.0.1)
  * warden (1.0.4)
```

### Installed Gems (Not Necessarily Related to Rails Project)

```
root@server-pc:/usr/local/blog# gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.1.0.rc4)
actionpack (3.1.0.rc4)
activemodel (3.1.0.rc4)
activerecord (3.1.0.rc4)
activeresource (3.1.0.rc4)
activesupport (3.1.0.rc4)
addressable (2.2.6)
ansi (1.3.0)
arel (2.1.3)
bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.15)
capistrano (2.6.1.pre, 2.6.0)
devise (1.4.2, 1.2.rc2)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.2.0)
faraday (0.5.7)
highline (1.6.2)
hike (1.1.0)
i18n (0.6.0)
jquery-rails (1.0.12)
kgio (2.6.0)
libv8 (3.3.10.2 x86-linux)
mail (2.3.0)
mime-types (1.16)
minitest (1.6.0)
multi_json (1.0.3, 0.0.5)
multipart-post (1.1.2)
net-ldap (0.1.1)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.1.4)
net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
nokogiri (1.4.7)
oa-basic (0.2.0.beta5)
oa-core (0.2.0.beta5)
oa-enterprise (0.2.0.beta5)
oa-more (0.2.0.beta5)
oa-oauth (0.2.0.beta5)
oa-openid (0.2.0.beta5)
oauth (0.4.5)
oauth2 (0.1.1)
omniauth (0.2.0.beta5)
orm_adapter (0.0.5)
polyglot (0.3.1)
pyu-ruby-sasl (0.0.3.3)
rack (1.3.1, 1.3.0)
rack-cache (1.0.2)
rack-mount (0.8.1)
rack-openid (1.2.0)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.0)
rails (3.1.0.rc4)
railties (3.1.0.rc4)
raindrops (0.7.0)
rake (0.9.2, 0.8.7)
rdoc (3.8, 2.5.8)
redcarpet (1.17.2)
rest-client (1.6.3)
ruby-openid (2.1.8)
ruby-openid-apps-discovery (1.2.0)
rubyntlm (0.1.1)
sass (3.1.4)
sass-rails (3.1.0.rc.4)
sprockets (2.0.0.beta.10)
sqlite3 (1.3.3)
therubyracer (0.9.2)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.2)
treetop (1.4.9)
turn (0.8.2)
tzinfo (0.3.29)
uglifier (1.0.0)
unicorn (4.0.1, 4.0.0.2.g19f7)
warden (1.0.4)
```

### Ruby Version

```
root@server-pc:/usr/local/blog# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [i686-linux]
```

This is on a server machine that I'm deploying it to, so I'd much rather have Ruby/Rails/Unicorn all as root.

### Where can I go from here to get Unicorn to properly work? Is it a misconfiguration (or lack of configuration) on my part, or is it a bug in Unicorn?

If there is anything I'm missing to help you help me please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have already activated rack 1.3.1, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.3.0. Consider using bundle exec.

...Consider using bundle exec.
...Consider using bundle exec.

..echo..

Comment: hmm, getting the same error while using `bundle exec unicorn_rails`